# add onclick attribute via jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a link that has onclick attribute, which unfortunately I cannot modify. What I wanna do is to call and execute another function before onclick function is called. Upon researching I figured out I cannot do that as onClick has first priority.

In order to achieve what I want here is what I want to do. Using Jquery remove onclick attribute and then add modified onclick attribute as soon as page loads.

For example: I currently have this.

```
<a href="#" class='myclass' onclick="Joomla.submitbutton('article.apply')">link</a>
```

I want to make it look like this

```
<a href="#" class='myclass' onclick="MyFunction(); Joomla.submitbutton('article.apply')">link</a>
```

That way, it will execute myfunction before default function.

I am not good with Jquery, can someone help.
Thanks.

Comment: where are you checking for the condition for removing and adding onclick function? javascript? codebehind?

Comment: @Krishna sorry I did not understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about cross-browser compatibility, but at least in Chrome, you can get a reference to the function to be called, remove the click handler, then bind your own:

http://jsfiddle.net/guXV3/

```
<a href="#" onclick="clickHandler();">click me</a>
```

---

```
function clickHandler() {
    console.log('inline handler');
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').each(function () {
        var originalHandler = $(this)[0].onclick;
        $(this).removeAttr('onclick');
        $(this).on('click', function () {
            console.log('new handler');
            originalHandler();
        });
    });

});
```

Clicking the link here logs `new handler`, then `inline handler`.

Comment: Thank You, I had to make some tweaks as per my need but this help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The attr() method sets or returns the attributes and values of the selected elements.

```
$('.myclass').attr('onclick', "myFunction()");
```

Answer (score 0):

To add your handler.

```
$('.myclass').click(function(){
    //your function code goes here.
});
```

To remove the previous handler.

```
$('.myclass').attr('onclick', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75vuj/2/) for full example.

```
$(function(){
   var $some_link = $('#some_link');
   var onClick = $some_link[0].onclick;
   $some_link.unbind('click', onClick);
   $some_link.attr('onclick', null);
   $some_link.on('click', function(e){ myBeforeCall(e); onClick(e); });
});

function myBeforeCall(){
   alert('Before');   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the inline you can do this:

```
$(function () {
    $('.myclass').attr('onclick', function (i, attr) {        
        return 'MyFunction();' + attr;
    });
})
```

This will change the html to the way you have it shown and `MyFunction()` fires first

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ng53/)**</kbd>

Comment: this was helpful as well. But since there were more than one link to deal with I had to use other code. Thanks